# Floyd Warshall Algorithm, Unrecognized errors

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, floyd-warshall

Having problems in taking input to this program. Also, don't know how to fill in those blank functions`textBox1_TextChanged`, `textBox9_TextChanged`. `Form1_Load`.Also what are these; `(object sender, EventArgs e)`? Help would be appreciated! This is how far I could get with the least experience I have in c#.

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.ComponentModel;
 using System.Data;
 using System.Drawing;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Windows.Forms;

 namespace Floyd_Warshall
 {
 public partial class Form1 : Form
 {
    string ab="";
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void textBox9_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ab = textBox9.Text;
    }
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    private void button10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int matrixDimention = Convert.ToInt32(ab);
        int[,] intValues = new int[matrixDimention, matrixDimention];
        string[] splitValues = textBox1.Text.Split(',');
        int[,] pathS = new int[matrixDimention, matrixDimention];
        for (int i = 0; i < splitValues.Length; i++)
        {
            intValues[i / (matrixDimention), i % (matrixDimention)] =  Convert.ToInt32(splitValues[i]);
            pathS[i / (matrixDimention), i % (matrixDimention)] = -1;
        }
            string displayString = "";
        for (int inner = 0; inner < intValues.GetLength(0); inner++)
        {
            for (int outer = 0; outer < intValues.GetLength(0); outer++)
                displayString += String.Format("{0}\t", intValues[inner, outer]);
                displayString += Environment.NewLine;
        }
        int n = (int)Math.Pow(matrixDimention, 2);
        string strn = n.ToString();

        MessageBox.Show("matrix" + strn + "in" + strn + "is\n\n\n" + displayString);

 for (int k = 1; k < n+1; k++)
 for (int i = 1; i < n+1; i++)
    for (int j = 1; j < n+1; j++)
        if (intValues[i, j] > intValues[i, k] + intValues[k, j]){                
            intValues[i, j] = intValues[i, k] + intValues[k, j];
            pathS[i,j] = k;
            string str_intvalues = intValues[i, j].ToString();
            MessageBox.Show("Shortest Path from i to j is: " + str_intvalues);
        }
        else{                
            string str_intvalues = intValues[i, j].ToString();
            MessageBox.Show("Shortest Path from i to j is: " + str_intvalues);
        }
    }


    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error exactly? On which line?

Comment: Every MessageBox is a design-flaw. You are going to show `(n+1)^3` of them.

Comment: Use the edit link to add detailed information about the error (exact text, which line etc).

Comment: the functions you mentioned are event handlers, so when you change the text (delete or type new text) in textbox9 the function (textBox9_TextChanged) will run, and so on.

Comment: @Henk Error: When ever giving any input in textbox9, I get This ERROR:Input String was not in a correct format

Comment: Is this correct? textbox9 takes input and also textbox1 takes somekind of input that goes into `splitValues`?

Comment: @Soner Error: When ever giving any input in textbox9, I get This ERROR:Input String was not in a correct format

Comment: @user3050101 On which line exactly? Debug your code please..

Comment: @user3050101 What is line 41? Come on.. Update it in your question.

Comment: @SonerGönül Line41: `intValues[i / (matrixDimention), i % (matrixDimention)] = Convert.ToInt32(splitValues[i]);`

Comment: @user3050101 What is the value of `splitValues[i]` when you look at the debugger?

Comment: @SonerGönül splitValues[i]=" ". Soner it would be a real help if you could try running this program on your system cause that way you would be able to understand the errors in a more better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of comments, I'm so glad **finally** we learn what is the error and which line gets it.

But I'm still suspect about your `splitValues[i]` is `" "` or `""`. Anyway, I try to answer both case.

If your `splitValues[i]` is `""`, that means one of your array value is empty string after that line;

```
string[] splitValues = textBox1.Text.Split(',');
```

In this case, you can use [`StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringsplitoptions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) enumeration like;

```
string[] splitValues = textBox1.Text.Split(new char[] {','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

If your `splitValues[i]` is `" "`, then you need to replace your spaces in your string with [`String.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method like;

```
string[] splitValues = textBox1.Text.Replace(" ", "").Split(new char[] {','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```